# How to make this custom imageview/textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, textview

I need to make for job this custom layout:
[image]

before I've used a custom frame with editText inside, but now I need a big one and so I need to make a drawable. 
The problem is that I'm not good with drawables and I have made only this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#EBEBE1" />

    <padding android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

anyone could help me to complete this?

Thanks

Comment: I think best way to use image in background. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @MayurRaval I think also this but the problem is that I use so much memory without a good result

Comment: i agree with mayur, use a 9 patch image for the background

Comment: What do you mean "a big one"? You can use `editText`, add the text as a `hint` attribute and set the font size as you wish.

Comment: @TDG because the photoframe of the image is limited in pixels...before I use this photoframe and an editText inside, but in this case it's a bad layout

Answer (score 0):

visit this link for Custom Textview : [Custom Textview](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-custom-font-textview/)

Answer (score 0):

I think so , These is the good way.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:hint="User Name / Email Address"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login_user_icon"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/etname"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etname"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login_password_icon"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/etpassword"
            android:inputType="textWebPassword"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```